# LaravelQuestion - Class admin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i found a issue it say 'Class admin does not exist'. Anything I missing for the issue? Thanks.

Here is my Route.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth' => 'admin']], function () {
  Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
  Route::get('profile','AdminController@profile');
  Route::get('/addProduct','AdminController@addProduct');
});
```

Here is my AdminController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AdminController extends Controller
{

  public function index(){
    return view('admin.index');
  }

  public function profile(){
    return view('admin.profile');
  }

  public function addProduct(){
    return view('admin.addProduct');
  }

}
```

Comment: The issue is here "'middleware'=> ['auth' => 'admin']]," what do you want to make?
If you have another middleware and you defined it like "admin" in Http/Kernel.php, you need to use comma instead of "=>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with in the route file to assign middlewares to route group

If you have two middlewares then assign like this `["auth", "admin"]` instead of `["auth" => "admin"]`.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
    Route::get('profile','AdminController@profile');
    Route::get('/addProduct','AdminController@addProduct');
});
```

Comment: is that typo in your question or in you application code?

Comment: i replace from "=>" to "," . thanks for the solution.